# Is there a way to infer a generic parameter from its properties?

Tags: typescript, generics, intellisense

I am trying to infer the type of one object property off another object property.

```js
type Dog = { name: string };
type Cat = { age: number};

class AnimalType<T> {

}

class AnimalTypeRegistry {
    static Dog: AnimalType<Dog>
    static Cat: AnimalType<Cat>
}

interface IConfig<T> {
    type: AnimalType<T>;
    init: Partial<T>;
}

class Config {
    get list(): IConfig<any>[] {
        return [
            {
                type: AnimalTypeRegistry.Dog,
                init: {
                    name: 'Bob' // Note - intellisense does not know this exists.
                }
            },
            {
                type: AnimalTypeRegistry.Cat,
                init: {
                    age: 3 // Note - intellisense does not know this exists.
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would expect that intellisense would be able to infer init to be of type Dog and that the name property exists. Instead it defaults to any (because of the function return type).

Comment: Why is the return type `IConfig<any>` if you are returning `IConfig<Dog>`?

Comment: The idea is that it could be expanded to be any array of IConfig<Dog> and IConfig<Cat>. I have updated the original example.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff going on here that makes this not a [mcve].  `AnimalType<T>` is an [empty class](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) with an [unused type parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--), which means it will behave strangely in ways unrelated to your issue.  You have [uninitialized static properties](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27899) in `AnimalTypeRegistry`, which will behave strangely in ways unrelated to your issue.

Comment: @user3854966 In that case you could make the return type `IConfig<Dog | Cat>`, or are you saying the return type can vary at runtime? You might also want to consider using [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) which is pretty close to what you are trying to model in your example.

Comment: @jcalz In this case further defining AnimalType or instantiating the properties in AnimalTypeRegistry does not effect the result. The issue is simply is there a way to return an array of Thing<T> where the T is infered.

Comment: @user3854966 IConfig<Dog | Cat> is close to what I want, the issue with that is properties from both Dog and Cat become valid. What I am really looking for is a IConfig<OneOf<[Dog, Cat]>> the idea being that only properties from one or the other are valid

Comment: @user3854966 Then I think you really want discriminated unions, which jcalz just posted an excellent answer concerning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `IConfig<any>` you will lose all type hinting because `any` could be, well, anything.

If you want to tell types apart enough to get meaningful IntelliSense for them, it helps to have a fixed [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of these types... and a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) in particular:

```
// Use a discriminated union for types
type Dog = { name: string; kind: "Dog" };
type Cat = { age: number; kind: "Cat" };
type Animal = Dog | Cat;
```

Here, `Animal` is the discriminated union: the discriminant property is called `kind` and you can use the string literal values `"Dog"` and `"Cat"` to discriminate which member of the union you have.

Sidestepping the "registry" and "`AnimalType<T>`" stuff in your code for now (you can get such functionality yourself if you care later), I will have `IConfig<K>` be dependent on the `kind` property `K` of the `Animal` in question:

```
// have IConfig<K> depend on the discriminant K
interface IConfig<K extends Animal["kind"]> {
  type: K;
  init: Partial<Extract<Animal, { kind: K }>>;
}
```

Note that the `init` property is `Partial<Extract<Animal, {kind: K}>>`.  The `Partial` makes sense to you, but `Extract<Animal, {kind: K}>` serves to [extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) the particular member of the `Animal` union whose `kind` property is `K`.

---

Then you want `list()` to output an array of `IConfig<"Dog"> | IConfig<"Cat">` elements.  You can generate that type from `Animal` programmatically, like this:

```
// SomeConfig is the union of all possible IConfig<K> types
type SomeConfig = { [K in Animal["kind"]]: IConfig<K> }[Animal["kind"]];
// type SomeConfig = IConfig<"Dog"> | IConfig<"Cat">
```

(we use a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and a [lookup](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) type to do that).

Note that you *don't* want `IConfig<"Dog" | "Cat">` (the union is in a different place), since those will allow merged elements like `{type: "Dog", init: { kind: "Cat" }}`, which I assume you don't want.

---

And finally you get the IntelliSense you want:

```
class Config {
  get list(): SomeConfig[] {
    return [
      {
        type: "Dog",
        init: { name: "woofers" } // you get intellisense here
      },
      {
        type: "Cat",
        init: { age: 5 } // you get intellisense here
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEFUGcFNQQ1AEwJaQMYCdkFtkDs4AXaRUAVz2QHs9QAzKjUQgTwAdpIBYAKFY9AARKgHNQAXlABvUAWzQAXKEiEseEQG5QAa3yIlAImEiDoAL4be-WAGEiE6fBGLZZbACNoGLbrz7QBnaEphZW7LAAgpTYcAA2DsagAD6gQZY8vCCgABZwAG6wAJI2NHTIIgA8ANIAfEjQHH6gNMzZsCjoWLgEeISgVbz4xBh0cGhFJXhllVWg0AAexH6QoFE4cQDaBr6IBgC6dVK8oMzhSlXpJ-jIhEoACnAYhMhxFQCiixhjhBVrMbEAGkcO3O5hqNXSZl4mTAAGUqPJJtNQKhWrAKNRaFQ6PBYvE2FRIJBkO5YhNSuVqnVrNw+OFQPDERSxJIZBtZvhVtFNts9Ps9kpisyqeYNn8eTt+ekstYGQjoEjyg4hVNKUZRAY6ikVdMKoEiJroTw0LE4ETUszpMdQM4+rFUIQABQASiUjIVzI2eytPBOJww0EIZAwtA21r9PojEeshmMBgB4aj11ujjkLgMAHcqNivJAQqAsiwqGQbYGUb1oHjUNA8DAcl5oImTmYE76o0c21HThxDEF402-cmlDI4M4lABWcwFsBFku28vEKswWuwNoBgdQzugPaXcy8TdAA)

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect!